# Symfony2 form widgets class

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm using Bootstrap3 and Symfony2.5

I need to add a html-class to the form elements to apply the bootstrap design for the input/select/textarea elements.

I can simply add it in the FormType class like this:

```
    'attr'=> array('class'=>'form-control')
```

But that would mean I have to do it for each and every element.

Alternative is overwriting all default twig-templates, but that would be overkill for just adding a class.

Is there a way to add a class in a more convenient way?

Comment: you should use that bundle [http://bootstrap.braincrafted.com/](http://bootstrap.braincrafted.com/) that comes with all feature you need

Comment: Good tip. The bundle does *a lot* for you, and some of it doesn't fit in my application. I doubt I can include the bundle. I will have a look at how the bundle manages to buildup the forms in bootstrap style. Either cherry picking from that or adjusting my existing code in a similar way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using bootstrap, you can use the form theme for bootstrap supplied with symfony.

Either by configuring this system wide in your `config.yml`:

```
twig:
    form_themes: [ 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig' ]
```

See: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-bootstrap-form-theme

Or setting it in your template for a single form in your page template:

```
{{ form_theme form 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig' }}
```

If you are here to figure out how to add your own class (or attribute) to default form themes. Also have a look at the bootstrap templates. It is quite simple to change the html.

If the default bootstrap 3 layout supplied by symfony is not to your liking, you can create your own and link to that template.
Have a look in the supplied bootstrap template in symfony on how to do just that.

The cookbook is also very helpful:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

Small sidenote: The bootstrap theme from symfony is only available since 2.6, while my question mentioned 2.5. If you are still running an earlier version of symfony you have a couple of options:

- upgrade symfony (highly recommended)
- copy the bootstrap templates into your own project (you might need to change a few bits though)
- create your own theme and use that one.